# Javascript illegal invocation - what to give as a context to CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype functions

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

So basically what I want to do is to copy CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype functions and store them in different variables. And great, I'm doing:

```
var c = CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype;
var moveTo = c.moveTo;
```

and after a couple of tries to avoid illegal invocation

```
moveTo(100, 100); // illegal invocation

moveTo.call($('canvas').getContext('2d'), 100, 100) /* 
^ which actually doesn't give any error
but doesn't seem to work in all cases either. I guess
I can't take any other context than the original one
*/

moveTo.call(CanvasRenderingContext2D, 100, 100) // illegal invocation

moveTo.call(CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype, 100, 100) // illegal

moveTo.call(CanvasRenderingContext2D.constructor (tried what I can) // illegal

moveTo.call(anything else, 100, 100) // bet what this time

(function() {
    moveTo(100, 100);
})(); // failed too
```

but every way of solving needed context for that has failed for me.

I want to store these functions, because I need to overwrite original ones in order to do some calculations, and then to actually see something I need to execute saved functions. I've read a lot about illegal invocations, here on stack overflow as well as on other websites, and i quite understand the problem - I need the original context so the function has it's variables etc.

```
// if we have

var a = something.run();

// then we can't do a(), because 'something' is lost, illegal invocation
```

That's how I understand that and I hope I'm not wrong.

Basically, what should I put in the context if everything fails? I have no clue what original context can be. By they way, please don't shout on me if I don't see obvious things here or don't know that context is blah blah blah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to store these functions, because I need to overwrite original ones in order to do some calculations, and then to actually see something I need to execute saved functions.

I assume you're looking for the following:

```
// keep track of the original function
var originalMoveTo = CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.moveTo;

// override
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.moveTo = function(...args) {
  // specific behavior
  console.log(...args);
  // call the original (your choice)
  originalMoveTo.apply(this, [...args]);
}
```

When you want to get back to normal:

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.moveTo = originalMoveTo;
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. Now I get how I should have done this.

Comment: This is the answer to your question, though, you should know that overriding native methods is considered bad practice (a quick search on google will tell you why).

Comment: I was modifying this function to access data it's given. If I created a new prototype function, it wouldn't help me. That's why i needed to modify itself and then invoke it anyway, but I could get access to it's arguments. But thank you for this comment anyway. I read about modifying native methods as you said.
Month after, but I reminded of replying to you just now, as writing next post. Sorry.